# How to add additional files to a package using NuGet?

Tags: nuget, chocolatey

**Attempt**

*Nuspec*

```
<files>
  <file src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/030/chocolateyautomatic/master/common/Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1" target="tools" />
</files>
```

**Result**

File is not added to tools directory

---

Running `cpack` indicates the following:

```
Calling 'C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\nuget.exe pack  -NoPackageAnalysis
Attempting to build package from 'eclipse.nuspec'.
The given path's format is not supported.
```

**Attempt two**

```
  <files>
    <file src="path\to\chocolateyautomatic\common\Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1" target="tools\Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1" />
  </files>
```

**Result Two**

The `The given path's format is not supported.` issue has been disappeared, but the `Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1` file is not added to the tools directory.

Comment: Is your <files></files> tag in a <package></package> tag? In other words, what does the whole file look like?

Comment: @Swoogan https://github.com/030/chocolateyautomatic/blob/master/eclipse/eclipse.nuspec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\..\common\Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1" target="tools\Uninstall-ChocolateyZipPackage030.ps1" />
    <file src="tools\*" target="tools" />
  </files>
```

adds all the files to the `nupkg` file.

Comment: you probably don't want to be using a hard coded path to the file.  You should instead use a relative path to the file.  That way, should you change the checkout directory of the repository, the file inclusions will still work.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Agreed but how could this be implemented? The common folder does not reside in eclipse folder such as the tools directory. I am checking [this documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference)

Comment: I would have thought you should have been able to do something similar to src="..\..\common\..." i.e. navigate up a folder relative to where the nuspec file is, and then navigate to the required folder path.

Comment: @GaryEwanPark `..\common` did not work, but `..\..\..\common` works as from the `_output` directory the common folder can be found now. Thank you.